# Where to start with api security testing?

Tags: rest

I have the backend api of an iOS application. I would like learn api testing on this.

How to begin with api security testing?Please suggest some tutorials and tools available online.

Comment: Anonymous - we explicitly do not do tools recommendation, and despite your edits, you have not addressed the problem - there are so many areas you need to learn that this question is unlikely to be answerable.

Answer (score 4):

Tips to ensure that your APIs are fully security tested :

**Automate:** Most of the testing approaches for security vulnerabilities that we have covered can be automated ([here’s a tool to help you do so](http://smartbear.com/product/ready-api/secure/overview/?_ga=1.229517659.674241289.1431693945)); and should definitely be done so – preferably against your production environment in some way. A system upgrade or server reconfiguration could be just as much a cause for a security vulnerability as bad development in the code of your APIs – and you definitely want to find out if such changes open up for unexpected vulnerabilities before anyone else.

**Stay on top:** [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) provides invaluable services and information on Internet related security vulnerabilities – and how to work against them. Make it a habit to check out their website and match their recommendations and findings against your APIs and infrastructure. Follow their guidelines – specifically those geared at APIs – and make sure you are doing what you can base on their resources.

**Finally – It’s your problem:** Security is probably not going to be fixed or worried by anyone else than you, – make sure you give it the same attention and focus as you do to functional, performance, usability, A/B testing, etc. The price to pay for leaked passwords or erased user data is too high to pay for you not to care (which I know you do).

Visit this, [page](http://blog.smartbear.com/readyapi/api-security-testing-how-to-hack-an-api-and-get-away-with-it-part-1-of-3/) it tell you how you can do security check on your API's

Comment: Gaurav, although links are always recommended I think a very short description at what he's looking at would help. Also, "hacking" does not always translate into testing.